# SciChart's Waterfall chart with .NET Blazor wrapper

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, .net-8.0, scichart

I'm trying to add this beautiful Waterfall chart SciChart has with this wrapper:
https://github.com/NRTDP/SciChartBlazor
But it looks like there is a problem with rendering 2d surfaces.

I've created a Chart.razor on Client side using new Blazor Web App with following code:

```
@page "/chart"
@using SciChartBlazor
@using SciChartBlazor.Axes
@using SciChartBlazor.DataSeries
@using SciChartBlazor.Modifiers
@using SciChartBlazor.RenderableSeries
@using SciChartBlazor.Services
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime 

<div id="@Id" @ref="_chart" style="height:600px" />
<button @onclick=Load>Load</button>
@code
{
    private string Id { get; set; } = "C" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private protected ElementReference _chart;

    SciChartBuilder _chartBuilder = default!;

    int _seriesCount = 10;

    private async void Load()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < _seriesCount; i++)
        {
            var XAxis = new NumericAxis()
                {
                    Id = $"X{i}",
                    MaxAutoTicks = 5,
                    DrawMajorGridLines = false,
                    GrowBy = new SciChartNumberRange(0, 0.2),
                    VisibleRange = new SciChartNumberRange(-1000.0, 1000.0),
                    VisibleRangeLimit = new SciChartNumberRange(-1000.0, 1000.0),
                    IsVisible = (i == 0),
                    //OverrideOffset = 0
                };

            await _chartBuilder.AddAxis(XAxis, AxisType.X);
            var YAxis = new NumericAxis()
                {
                    Id = $"Y{i}",
                    MaxAutoTicks = 5,
                    DrawMajorGridLines = false,
                    VisibleRange = new SciChartNumberRange(-100.0, 100.0),
                    VisibleRangeLimit = new SciChartNumberRange(-1000.0, 1000.0),
                    IsVisible = (i == 0),
                    //OverrideOffset = 0
                };

            await _chartBuilder.AddAxis(YAxis, AxisType.Y);

            double[] x = new double[10];
            double[] y = new double[10];


            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                x[j] = (double)j;
                y[j] = Math.Sin(j) * 100 + i;
            }

            var ser = new XyDataSeries<double, double>(x, y) { DataSeriesName = $"N{i}" };

            var fastLineRenderableSeries = new SciChartBlazor.RenderableSeries.FastLineRenderableSeries<double, double>(ser)
                { Id = $"S{i}", XAxisId = $"X{i}", YAxisId = $"Y{i}", StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = "#64BAE4" };

            await _chartBuilder.AddSeries(fastLineRenderableSeries);
        }

    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //Create the chart
            _chartBuilder = new SciChartBuilder(_chart, JsRuntime, new SciChartBlazorService(JsRuntime, new SciChartOptions()));
            await _chartBuilder.CreateChart();
        }
    }
}
```

With _seriesCount equals 1 it builds a simple chart, but adding more series returns an error in a line:

```
 this.nativeArgs.StartIndex = rp.indexesRange.min
```

Full trace:

```
Error from chart in div Ced51579e-26cc-4536-96e2-49f46254f9db: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'min')
    at ExtremeResamplerHelper.resetAndFillBasicNativeArgs (ExtremeResamplerHelper.js:178:54)
    at ExtremeResamplerHelper.needsResampling (ExtremeResamplerHelper.js:50:18)
    at BaseRenderableSeries.needsResampling (BaseRenderableSeries.js:935:37)
    at SciChartRenderer.resampleSeries (SciChartRenderer.js:65:17)
    at SciChartRenderer.prepareSeriesRenderData (SciChartRenderer.js:328:57)
    at SciChartRenderer.render (SciChartRenderer.js:144:35)
    at SciChartSurface.doDrawingLoop (SciChartSurface.js:707:35)
    at SciChartSurface.onRenderSurfaceDraw (SciChartSurface.js:1337:18)
    at RenderSurface.onRenderTimeElapsed (RenderSurface.js:37:14)
    at Object.Draw (createMaster.js:294:60)
```

Following this stacktrace at SciChartRenderer.resampleSeries (SciChartRenderer.js:65:17)

```
 var rp = new ResamplingParams_1.ResamplingParams(seriesViewRect, rs, xAxis);
```

where

```
var ResamplingParams_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! ../Numerics/Resamplers/ResamplingParams */ "./node_modules/scichart/Charting/Numerics/Resamplers/ResamplingParams.js");
```

it looks like rp is not created correctly but I don't understand why?

Ps I've downloaded the package from git and didn't use NuGet. Also you can find js equivalent of this here https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.JS.Examples/blob/master/Examples/src/components/Examples/FeaturedApps/ScientificCharts/InteractiveWaterfallChart/index.tsx

Also you will need to add this line in your App.razor:

```
<script async src="_content/SciChartBlazor/SciChart/sciChartBlazorJson.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK a couple of things here. It's possible this is an error in the SciChartBlazor wrapper, or an error in the way you've set the code up, or a bug in SciChart itself. To isolate these are you able to upload somewhere (to git) a minimal solution to reproduce? That'll make it easier to debug. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I'll add one in my repo shortly, meanwhile, I went through source of the library and found out that the axis are not added correctly. I made an issue on there GitHub https://github.com/mr-azazael/LightweightCharts.Blazor/issues/6

Comment: You may have reported that in the wrong repo 

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson yea... I changed it: https://github.com/NRTDP/SciChartBlazor/issues/28  And the link to project is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SAgvMb5meCXiHMOZin3F9W2FDjQv3m_J/view?usp=sharing